# Getting mail on windows logon with username of logged-in user

Tags: windows, windows-server, event-viewer, windows-administration, adsutil.vbs

I am trying to create action task that will send mail when anyone logs in to a particular system with username of a logged in user.

I am very new to this task since I never worked as a system admin anytime.
What I think I should do is to specify a program to execute when log-in event occurs, but am not aware of what sort of program I should. I thought it should be `exe` file.

**Q.** Can I specify vbs file?

**Q.** If yes what should be the content of `vbs`? Is there any ready made script available for accomplishing the same?

**Q.** Also not sure where to specify it. Is this below screen where I can specify it:
[image]

**Q.** Also this I am trying to do on windows 7 which is in network with AD configured on Windows Server 2008. So where should I specify the action? on server or on this particular Win 7 machine?

Answer (score 1):

If u have AD, you can use logon scripts (*.cmd | *.vbs) and specify it for each clients.
To send email by the command line, try to use smth like `telnet smtp.gmail.com 25/465`.